# Laravel: how to pass id to modal box for editing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5 app, I'm using a model to add items. In my view file, I'm doing it as follows

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-item-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-create">Create new item</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="add-item-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="loginmodal-container">
        .... <form comes here>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As said, this works for adding items.

I now also want to use a similar logic for editing items. So I have added the following on my page

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-auction-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-warning"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="add-item-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="loginmodal-container">
        .... <form comes here>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem however is that I need to pass the id of the current item (I wish to edit) to the modal box so that the modal can display the values for the item I wish to update.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem many times in the past. What I do (and it always worked) is pass the item id you wish to update as a data property to the link that opens the modal like so:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-auction-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-warning" data-item-id="10">Open modal</a>
```

Then, create a js function that gets the item id when the modal is shown from the data-item-id attribute and update the form data as appropriate for your case. I can imagine two ways:
1. Update the action url. Example: 'update/product/10'
2. Update a hidden field with the item id.

Sample js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $updateModal = $('#update-modal');
    $('.list-item-update').on('click', function (evn) { // this is the "a" tag
    evn.preventDefault();

    $updateModal.modal('show');
    var resourceId = $(this).data('itemId'),
        $pressedButton = $(this);

    $updateModal.find('.confirm-btn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var submitUrl = '/update/product/' + resourceId,
            form = $('#product-update-form'); // change with your form

        form.attr('action', submitUrl);
        form.submit();
    });
  });
});
```

Pretty much everything goes down to modifying the DOM with js based on a data attribute you provided.

Comment: Thanks. I like your suggestion of passing a data-item-id. I would like to update the action URL so ideally I can use JS to extract the value from that data-item-id. Do you happen to have some sample JS code I could try for this. I'm not very good at JS I'm afraid.

Comment: This is quite complex for a JS newbie like me :-) I initially only changed  #product-update-form to #edit-event-modal (the name of my modal). But that does not work.... So (in line 2): should I give my modal then an id of id="update-modal"? Does the  $(this).data('itemId') correspond to my "data-item-id".

Comment: @wiwa1978 #update-modal should be your modal id. In your case: #add-item-modal And  $(this).data('itemId') is your data-item-id property. Tell me if you got it to work.

Comment: Not working yet. I put a console.log statement after $('.list-item-update').on('click', function (evn) { but it does not print it. When I put it before it, it prints the statement. So seems like it does not het into that function. What is this .list-item-update exactly?

Comment: as the comment on the right says - // this is the "a" tag. This is your link that triggers the modal. You should substitute .list-item-update with your <a> selector